# Options +Indexes will not show filenames

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I show file names in the directory listing on apache server.

I am using

```
Options +Indexes
```

I have also tried

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

in the root but I am not able to see file names only an empty structure

There are 4-5 files of different names and extension available in the folder.

[image]

Comment: What are the file permissions?

Comment: I had read permissions on them rw-r--r-- . I also tried one with full rwxrwxrwx but did not help.

Comment: Check if your configurations have `IndexIgnore` directive. http://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_autoindex#indexignore

Comment: I found IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t in httpd-autoindex.conf I disabled , restarted server but no effect.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right directory your files are in?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I found the problem. It was IndexIgnore in another root folder which was overwriting . it was IndexIgnore * which I had to disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're unable to generate auto index even after dabbling with file permissions; it is generally all thanks to [`IndexIgnore` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore).

Check your server settings, going one step above from the current htaccess at a time. See where you encounter it.